# 4NF Database / Fourth normal form

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

Who could help me with 4NF? Is this the 4NF?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This design does not qualifies any normal form, because the foreign key reference are not properly defined. Understand the requirement and design the model in such a way. Understand the consistency of the data and decide whether to use ER modelling or Dimensional modelling. Below are the few links which makes you to understand the data modelling.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-of-er-model/

https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/